# Can I specify a particular non-client zone which is not a square or a rectangle?

Tags: windows

`WM_NCCALCSIZE` can control the NC zone of a window. The parameters specified the window area and the NC zone before and after changes.

However , in some particular situation, I need to modify the NC zone which contains a serials cube area, as the photo below point out.
[image]

As you see, the right part of the non-client zone just occupied part of the right side, the right-top edge is belonging the client zone . how to cut this area out, make it part of client window zone ?

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: The client rectangle must be a rectangle. Anything that is outside the client rectangle is the non-client zone.

Comment: got your point ! thank you . any tricks to implement what I'm doing ?@RaymondChen

Comment: Not sure what specific problem you are trying to solve, but [SelectClipRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectcliprgn) may be part of that solution.